# Ajax not retrieving data every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do i get data pulled in every 5 seconds? for some reason it is not working

here's my code, but not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            setTimeout(function() {
              $.ajax({ 
            url: 'test_api.php', 
            data: "", dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(rows) { 

                for (var i in rows) { 

                    var row = rows[i]; 

                    var availability = row[3]; 

                    var hostName = row[2];

                    var intranet = row[6];

                    var timeRespons = row[4]; 

                    $('body').append("<b>availability: </b>"+availability+"<b> hostName: </b>"+hostName+
                    "<b> intranet: </b>"+intranet+"<b> timeResponse: </b>"+timeRespons) .append("<hr />");

                    } 
                }
            });
            }, 5000);

        });
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`, if you want to call function every 5 seconds. The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Where as The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

Change your code

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({ 
    url: 'test_api.php', 
    data: "", dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(rows) { 
        $('body').html(''); //Clear content
        for (var i in rows) { 
            var row = rows[i]; 
            var availability = row[3]; 
            var hostName = row[2];
            var intranet = row[6];
            var timeRespons = row[4]; 
            $('body').append("<b>availability: </b>"+availability+"<b> hostName: </b>"+hostName+
            "<b> intranet: </b>"+intranet+"<b> timeResponse: </b>"+timeRespons) .append("<hr />");
            } 
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

If you want to overwrite `body` content, use `$('body').html(htmlstring)`;

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TTvHA/)

Comment: yes, but setInterval() is keep appending the data instead of refreshing

Comment: @Marcel, As you have specified `$('body').append()`. If you don't want to append use `$('body').html`.

Comment: Yes, I manage that. but the problem now is that this is returning only one row with data instead of 5 or 6. When I used append this returned all the rows from the array but .html() return only last row from the array :(

Comment: @Marcel, got the issue I have updated answer. put `$('body').html('');` before for loop and then use `$('body').append` as you were using.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `setTimeout`, use `setInterval`.

`setTimeout` runs once after the time specified has passed.

`setInterval` runs continuously at the specified time until you stop it with `clearInterval`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'test_api.php',
        data: "", dataType: 'json',
        success: function(rows) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                var row = rows[i];
                var availability = row[3];
                var hostName = row[2];
                var intranet = row[6];
                var timeRespons = row[4];

                $('body').append("<b>availability: </b>" + availability + 
                                 "<b> hostName: </b>" + hostName +
                                 "<b> intranet: </b>" + intranet + 
                                 "<b> timeResponse: </b>"+timeRespons) 
                         .append("<hr />");

                }
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```